# Trouble wrapping Google Maps - Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to wrap the Google Maps Javascript API in a Javascript class that I can reuse in multiple places in my webapp. The code at the bottom contains the basics of the concept. Once I get this working, I'll be adding more logic to the My.Map class to automate adding markers and such from my API.

The idea is that a page with one or more maps would have a script like so at the bottom.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    var map1 = new My.Map('#map1Canvas', { zoom: 10 });
    var map2 = new My.Map('#map2Canvas');
    My.Map.renderAll('MyGoogleMapsApiKeyGoesHere');
  }); 
</script>
```

When I run this code, the DIVs are partially initialized - the get the border and gray background.  However, they don't get fully initialized and when I click or drag on them, I'm getting errors in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

Adding console.log() statements in various places tells me that the dynamic insertion of the  tag for the Google Maps API is working and Map._renderAllCallback() is being run. I'm also seeing that the google.maps.Map() call is being made once for each of the two instances. If I only init one of them (i.e. comment out the "var map2 = ..." line) I get the same.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

The code for the "My" library is below.

```
(function(global) {

    Map._maps = {};

    function Map(selector, opts) {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.opts = opts || {};
        this.gmaps = []; 
        if (selector in Map._maps) {
            throw new Error("Duplicate My.Map selector; \""+selector+"\"!");
        }
        Map._maps[selector] = this;
    }   

    Map.prototype = {
        selector: null,
        opts: {}, 

        constructor: Map,

        _render: function() {
            var that = this 
            $(this.selector).each(function(idx, el) {
                that.gmaps.push(new google.maps.Map(el, that.opts));
            }); 
        }   
    };

    Map.renderAll = function(mapsKey) {
        if (!mapsKey) { throw new Error("Missing Google Maps API Key!"); }
        var script = $('<script>', {
            type: 'text/javascript',
            src: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='
                 + mapsKey + '&callback=My.Map._renderAllCallback'
        });
        script[0].setAttribute('async', '');
        script[0].setAttribute('defer', '');
        $(document.body).append(script);
    };

    Map._renderAllCallback = function() {
        console.log("Callback() _maps", Map._maps);
        for (var key in Map._maps) {
            if (Map._maps.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log("Callback() key", key, Map._maps[key]);
                Map._maps[key]._render();
            }
        }
    };

    global.My = {
        Map: Map,
    };

})(this);
```

Comment: I don't see the error reported in the title with the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing the maps correctly.  There are two required parameters: `zoom` and `center`.  You can initialize both with a `fitBounds` operation or with an object that automatically zooms and centers the map (like the DirectionsService or KmlLayer, etc).

This works for me:

```
$(function () {
  var map1 = new My.Map('#map1Canvas', { zoom: 10, center: {lat: 45, lng:-72 } });
  var map2 = new My.Map('#map2Canvas', { zoom: 10, center: {lat: 45, lng:-112 } });
  My.Map.renderAll();
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2vk0qfve/)

**code snippet:**

```js
(function(global) {

  Map._maps = {};

  function Map(selector, opts) {
    this.selector = selector;
    this.opts = opts || {};
    this.gmaps = [];
    if (selector in Map._maps) {
      throw new Error("Duplicate My.Map selector; \"" + selector + "\"!");
    }
    Map._maps[selector] = this;
  }

  Map.prototype = {
    selector: null,
    opts: {},

    constructor: Map,

    _render: function() {
      var that = this
      $(this.selector).each(function(idx, el) {
        that.gmaps.push(new google.maps.Map(el, that.opts));
      });
    }
  };

  Map.renderAll = function(mapsKey) {
    // keys not currently required on SO or jsfiddle
    // if (!mapsKey) { throw new Error("Missing Google Maps API Key!"); }
    var script = $('<script>', {
      type: 'text/javascript',
      src: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=My.Map._renderAllCallback'
    });
    script[0].setAttribute('async', '');
    script[0].setAttribute('defer', '');
    $(document.body).append(script);
  };

  Map._renderAllCallback = function() {
    for (var key in Map._maps) {
      if (Map._maps.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        Map._maps[key]._render();
      }
    }
  };

  global.My = {
    Map: Map,
  };

})(this);
```

```css
html,
body,
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map1Canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#map2Canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map1Canvas"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="map2Canvas"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var map1 = new My.Map('#map1Canvas', {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {
        lat: 45,
        lng: -72
      }
    });
    var map2 = new My.Map('#map2Canvas', {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {
        lat: 45,
        lng: -112
      }
    });
    My.Map.renderAll();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Nuts!  That's embarrassing.  Thanks much.